# Woocommerce Coupon Allowed emails restrictions not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

I create New coupon code with Allowed emails restrictions in Woocommerce. But Guest Users(Guest User Emails Not Registered Allowed emails Fields) get Discounts using this coupons.

Comment: Open an issue in Github WooCommerce…

Comment: This was posted some time ago. I am having the same issue. Have you gotten a solution in the last 6 months?